# How bit endianness affects bitwise shifts and file IO in C?

Tags: c, endianness, bit

Let **L** and **B** be two machines. **L** order its *bits* from LSB
(Least Significant Bit) to MSB (Most Significant Bit) while **B** order
from MSB to LSB. Or, in other words, **L** uses Little Endian while
**B** uses Big Endian *bit* - not to be confused with byte - ordering.

Problem 1 **SOLVED**:

We are writing the following code which we want to be portable:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char a = 1;
    a <<= 1;

    printf("a = %d\n", (int) a);

    return 0;
}
```

on **L**, it will print 2, but what happens on **B**? Will it shift the
1 out and print 0?.

**SOLUTION:** The C99 definition at 6.5.7 says it that, at least on
unsigned integer types, `<<` and `>>` will multiply and divide by 2
respectively.

Problem 2:

We are writing the following code which we want to be portable:

READ program:

```
/* program READ */
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* fp;
    unsigned char a;

    fp = fopen("data.dat", "rb");
    fread(&a, 1, 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

and WRITE program:

```
/* program WRITE */
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* fp;
    unsigned char a = 1;

    fp = fopen("data.dat", "wb");
    fwrite(&a, 1, 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

what happens if we run WRITE on **L**, move the data file to **B** and
run READ there? And if we run WRITE on **B** and then READ on **L**?

Sorry if this is a FAQ. I googled for hours without luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bit Endianness doesn't affect data stored on disks in bytes.  Byte Endianness will.

Bit Endianness is something that matters for serial interfaces where a byte is sent one bit at a time, and the sender and receiver need to agree on the byte order.  For example, bit order in [SPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface_Bus) devices varies and you need to reference the data sheet before attempting to read from the device.

Here's what [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endian#.22Bit_endianness.22) says on bit endianness:

> The terms bit endianness or bit-level
>   endianness are seldom used when
>   talking about the representation of a
>   stored value, as they are only
>   meaningful for the rare computer
>   architectures where each individual
>   bit has a unique address. They are
>   used however to refer to the
>   transmission order of bits over a
>   serial medium. Most often that order
>   is transparently managed by the
>   hardware and is the bit-level analogue
>   of little-endian (low-bit first),
>   although protocols exist which require
>   the opposite ordering (e.g. I²C). In
>   networking, the decision about the
>   order of transmission of bits is made
>   in the very bottom of the data link
>   layer of the OSI model.

In your case, the physical hard drive interface defines the bit order, regardless of the processor that's going to read or write it.

Comment: So you say Endianness of bits is irrelevant at file IO. Is this some kind of standard? If so, can you post links to where it is defined?

Comment: File I/O is defined as reading complete bytes.  You can't read less than a byte from a file.  The bit order depends on the interface to the storage medium (SCSI, SATA, USB Mass Storage, etc.) and I would imagine that only serial interfaces (e.g., SATA butnot PATA) are affected.

Comment: Hmm, no, unlike cpu cores these interfaces are actually described in fine detail in a standard so that devices from different manufacturers will work together.

Comment: Hm... After all, bit endianness is relevant or not when reading and writing?

Comment: @rogi: Not relevant when reading and writing files.  Not relevant when opening a serial port or TCP socket in C and sending bytes.  Relevant when writing device drivers or doing embedded programming and sending serial data one bit at a time.

Comment: After reading your answer about 30 times I finally saw teh light. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The `number>>n` and `number<<n` do not push and pull bits right and left. They divide and multiply `number` by `2^n`. It's worth noting that the behavior of these shifts is not defined if `n` is negative or is larger than the width of the datatype of `number`.

According to section 6.5.7 from the [C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf#page=96):

> The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated bits are filled with zeros. **If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of the result is E1 × 2^E2**, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value representable in the result type. If E1 has a signed type and nonnegative value, and E1 × 2^E2 is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.
>
> The result of E1 >> E2 is E1 right-shifted E2 bit positions. I**f E1 has an unsigned type or if E1 has a signed type and a nonnegative value, the value of the result is the integral part of the quotient of E1 / 2^E2**. If E1 has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value is implementation-defined.

For all the compiler cares, the bits could be stacked vertically :)

Comment: Technically, they don't. There's a difference between `/2` and `>>1` when using negative numbers. Also, since some CPUs are much slower to divide than to shift, they will certainly internally do a shift operation.

Comment: In fact you are almost right. C99 standard define >> and << as division and multiplication by 2 on unsigned integers. I will add this to question.

Comment: Section 6.5.7 is somewhat dense for mignight ... but the resulting *value* of an expression using bitwise shifts is described with division and multiplication by 2. Anyway +1 @Ebo for the difference regarding negative numbers

Comment: @EboMike: when shifting signed integers, the sign bit is extended.  `-4 >> 1` is the same as `-4 / 2` -- `-2`.  In my experience, `>> 1` is the same as `/ 2`.

Comment: @tomlogic In fact, signed integer shifting is moar tricky than that. C99 6.5.7 says this is implementation-defined.

Comment: `-9 / 2 = -4`. `-9 >> 1 = -5`. Division and shift are NOT the same.

Comment: @EboMike: Wow, I see the light now.  I'm now going to have to go back and make sure that some compiler optimizations I worked on only apply to unsigned values!

Comment: @EboMike not for **negative** **signed** integers.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't really such a thing as bit-endianness, at least as far as C is concerned.  `CHAR_BIT` has to be at least 8 according to the spec, so accesses to any objects smaller than that is pretty much meaningless to a standard C program.  Regardless of how the hardware stores a byte - LSB or MSB first - it doesn't affect your program at all.  `myVar & 1` returns the right bit in either case.

If you need to interact with some kind of serial interface and reconstitute bytes from it, that's a different story.  Your own machine's 'bit-endianness' still doesn't affect anything, but the bit order of the interface certainly does.

Now, as to your specific question and the program you've shown.  Your programs are almost 100% portable.  Neither bit- nor byte-endianness affects them.  What *might* affect them is if `CHAR_BIT` were different on each platform.  One computer might write more data than the other one would read, or vice versa.

Comment: Your answer made me think: if character size is implementation-defined, there is just no way to make any portable file with fread and fwrite. Am I right?

Comment: @rogi, sure it can be portable - just make sure you're copying the right number of bits!  You can use the `CHAR_BIT` constant to keep your programs portable.

Comment: Oh. Thanks for your answer! I was gonna ask another question about this issue!

Answer (score 2):

Bit-shifting is not affected by endianness.  Binary file I/O normally is, but not in your case since you are only writing a single byte.

Comment: I'm concerned about _bit_ endianness and not _byte_.

Comment: What platform has a different "bit" endianness?!

Comment: In any case, anything not giving you "2" as the result of "1 << 1" needs to go to the junkyard, and fast.

Comment: I'm not aware of any core in the past 3 decades that reversed the bit order.

Comment: So does 680x0. But that's byte order, not bit order.

Answer (score 0):

Endianness will not affect you unless a) you read something from memory using a different type than you used to write it to, or if you read something from a file that was written with a machine using different endianness.

i.e.

```
int data;
char charVal;

*data = 1;
charval = *((char *) data);  // Different result based on endianness
```

Or your example two, assuming you're using a type larger than char.

Comment: Wat? I want to know about _bits_ and not _bytes_. Your example is an undefined behaviour.

Comment: See my comments to the other answer. You might have misunderstood something. Big-endian and little-endian refers to the byte order.

Comment: I refer to _bit_ order. Teh question emphasizes that.

Comment: Yes, and both Hans and myself have been trying to tell you that what you're talking about doesn't exist in real life.

Comment: Actually, the Wikipedia article on [Endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endian) has a section on [Bit Endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endian#.22Bit_endianness.22).

Comment: @tomlogic: It does, I should clarify. Bit Endianness doesn't affect you when your smallest atomic read operation is a byte (the article itself mentions how bit endianness this is relevant). When programming in C and dealing with data stored in memory, only byte order matters.

Comment: @EboMike: Agreed, bit endianness does exist, but isn't relevant when talking about file I/O or data stored in memory.