# Big-endian architecture 101

Tags: endianness

I only know what I know through my experience through Computer Architecture course. Little-endian stores the LSB on the right and MSB on the left and on Big-endian it's vice versa.

That would mean a byte representation of 18 is 0001 0010 and on Big-endian it would be 0100 1000.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to ask a question.

Comment: The B in MSB and LSB means *byte*, not *bit*. Further discussion on this can be found in this recent question: [How bit endianness affects bitwise shifts and file IO in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493515/how-bit-endianness-affects-bitwise-shifts-and-file-io-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not like that, say you have `3,168,415,017` as 32 bit unsigned number here is the Little Endian binary representation of it:

```
10111100 11011010 00101101 00101001
```

While the Big Endian representation would flip the BYTES but not the BITS inside the bytes.

```
00101001 00101101 11011010 10111100
```

Note that the bytes are flipped but the order of bits inside of each remains the same.

Comment: Any links for understanding the big-endian architecture for handling integer data?

Comment: Digits within a number are traditionally written in big-endian format, but there are times when digits may be written LSB-first, most notably when the written form is supposed to represent, left-to-right, the chronological sequence in which data will be sent on an LSB-first communications link.

Comment: @Argote I found an article that states that bits are usually differently inside bytes between big and and little endian architectures (http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6788). Is this article wrong? If it is wrong, could you provide a reference for your answer? From what I have read on other articles on Stackoverflow concerning bit endianness (see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5493700/1911431), bytes are a sort of indivisible unit of memory whose contents cannot are not addressable (with the implication that bit endianness only matters in communication protocols between devices).